# ValueError in resnet 50

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, resnet

I tried training my dataset with resnet50:

```
class_names = train_ds.class_names
num_classes=len(class_names)


resnet_model = Sequential()

pretrained_model= tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                   input_shape=(180,180,3),
                   pooling='avg',classes=num_classes,
                   weights='imagenet')
for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable=False

resnet_model.add(pretrained_model) 
resnet_model.add(Flatten())
resnet_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')) 

resnet_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = resnet_model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=50)
```

But this Error keeps appearing:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-f961e6d0e704> in <module>()
----> 1 history = resnet_model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=50)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 810, in train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1665, in categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4994, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 14) are incompatible
```

I thought the Dense layer is connected to the number of classes, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work correctly. It's probably some stupid mistake I made but I'm out of ideas. Thank you for any help

Comment: If your labels are given as indices, you need to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as your loss. `categorical_crossentropy` is intended for labels being in a one-hot format. I'm _assuming_ this is the issue but cannot say for sure given we can't see the labels.

Comment: @xdurch0 You're right, thank you very much